# How to get bundle options qty ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, bundle-product, order-items

How to get bundle product options qty from `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`  ?

Comment: try with this - $item->getQtyOrdered();

Comment: Anas Mansuri , thanks